# Empirical Bayes vs "non-informative" priors

Tags: bayesian, model-selection, prior, empirical-bayes

I am familiar with the mechanics with both methods, but don't know what factors I should consider when choosing between these two approaches for adjusting a prior.

I would imagine that, on a case by case basis, one could run posterior predictive checks, compare model complexity, etc. to see which model gives the best simplicity-fitting tradeoff.

But in the general case, how does one make the decision of whether to use non-informative priors vs Empirical Bayes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If those are your only two options, then you should use empirical Bayes if and only if you have a hierarchical model.  A hierarchical model is when you have multiple parameters $\theta_i$ that are assumed to come from the same prior distribution $p(\theta)$.  In this situation, empirical Bayes is a safer choice than setting $p(\theta)$ to be a non-informative prior.  If you don't have a hierarchical model, then you can't sensibly learn the prior from data, so the non-informative prior is the better option.

Comment: Thank you Tom. That is certainly my case (having a hierarchical model). Aside from these two options, MAP-II (i.e. MAP on the the hyperparameters using a prior on the priors) and a full Bayes treatment, is there any other way to adjust or inform the choice of the prior?

Comment: Empirical Bayes is only one of the possible approximations to a full Bayes treatment.  There are many other approximation algorithms available, such as [Variational Bayes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_Bayesian_methods) and [Expectation Propagation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation_propagation).